# A medicinal drink turning into a pleasure drink mid-guzzle

Tags: halacha, blessing, medicine, hanaah-benefit, shehakol-beracha

I am not, to my knowledge, thirsty, but I need to take a pill with water, so I do so without a *beracha* (see [Shulchan Aruch OC 204:7](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.204.7?lang=bi)). As I swallow the pill, I realise that I am enjoying the water, and realise I actually am a bit thirsty (quite common in today's day and age to not feel thirsty when we actually are) and wish to continue to drink. Should I stop, say a *beracha* and then continue to drink, or as I am already drinking, should I just continue? If the latter, should I try and say a *shehakol* on something legitimate asap and have the previous drinking in mind?

Comment: I don't understand the הווה אמינא to think that you wouldn't bless after the first gulp if you intend to continue drinking. You know that are drinking for thirst after that (the pill went down, and you consciously became aware of the thirst). What am I missing?

Comment: apparently the question refers specifically to דבר הגזול

Comment: @Deuteronomy I know this won't satisfy, but the only real hava amina I have is my intuition. I don't think it is so black and white a case, and I get the impression from my time looking at responsa that this is the type of question that might bring up some interesting discussion. Maybe not!

Comment: Thanks. I hope you get what you're looking for :)

Comment: I don't think enjoying the water is the distinction but rather how much water was needed to swallow the pill. Logically drinking beyond the need to swallow the pill for quenching one's thirst would require a bracha. Another option which would remove any doubt would be to add a small amount of lemon juice to the water and thus would require a bracha before drinking all of the time (unless there was an additional reason not to such as already having made bore pri hagafen)

Comment: @Dude have you ever swallowed a pill without enough water and had it get stuck somewhere in your oesophagus, and give you some severe pains later on? I'm not sure we can make a clear cut measurement of what is the right amount of water :/

Comment: @RabbiKaii yes I have and I don't think we have to split hairs or droplets here. the right amount of water is easy to measure. Once you've swallowed the pill successfully. Whether that's a very little bit or a whole lot depends on the person and the size of the pill. Once you've clearly swallowed it then drinking further would be for another purpose

Comment: There is a discussion in the poskim about an inverse case, where someone is no longer thirsty but still didn’t finish enough for bracha achrona. RSZ, and R Nissim Karelitz feel that the entire drink is always considered for thirst even if part of it wasn’t. R Wosner and others pasken with the Gr”a who said it was possible to split and half is not counted for thirst. Not sure if anyone holds your case is possible, to become thirsty in middle